# How call jQuery method in component?

Tags: jquery, angular

I try call jQuery method in my own component, but I can't call this method after HTML rendering. I was trying in this way:

```
declare var $: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'some-component',
    template: `
       <div *ngFor="let id of fieldIds" class="form-field">
          <input type="text" id="{{id}}" class="form-control"/>
       </div>
    `
})
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, AfterViewChecked {

   fieldIds: string[] = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'];

   constructor() {}

   ngOnInit(): void {
      console.log($("#def"));
      //is undefined
   }

   ngAfterViewInit(): void {
      console.log($("#def"));
      //is undefined
   }

   ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
      console.log($("#def"));
      //exist, but method is called too many times
   }
}
```

But only method, which execute after HTML rendering is ngAfterViewChecked. Its called many times, but I have to call it only one time. How can I make this?

Comment: Why do you need to use JQuery like that?

Comment: I dont need, I have to. :) It's not a exact case. I have to using jQuery-UI datepicker on some inputs on form (customer requirement), but form must be dynamic (technical requirement). I know that mixed jQuery and angular2 is bed idea, but it's not up to me

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to

1. import ElementRef

   import { ElementRef } from @angular/core
2. inject it to your component

   constructor(private elementRef ElementRef) {}
3. inside ngOnInit

   let element = $(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find('#def');

I did not test it but give it a try!